# my code isn't working can someone fix it?

Tags: roblox

I'm not getting an error but when I click nothing is happening

```
local collect = game.StarterGui.Backpack.LocalScript.Collect
local rod = script.Parent
local equipped = false
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")

if rod.Equipped then
    equipped = true
end

if rod.Unequipped then
    equipped = false
end

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(gp, input)
    if input == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 and equipped == true then
        collect.Value = collect.Value + 1
    end
end)
```

this is part of the backpack system where you click and get 1 added to your backpack but it isn't adding anything when I try.

Comment: Heyo, it's not enough to simply say that your code isn't working. Be specific about _what_ isn't working. Is your code running at all? Is this a Script or a LocalScript? Where is it located? Have you tried using `print` statements to see that anything is happening at all? Is the event happening but the UI not updating? What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```html
-- Server Script inside the tool
script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
game.Players[script.Parent.Parent.Name].PlayerGui.Backpack.LocalScript.Collect.Value+=1
end)
```